# Changing javafx button color on click?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I know I can set a color by using the pressed pseudo selector:

```
myButton:pressed{}
```

Problem is, im trying to do this in code by overriding the css background color from my stylesheet by doing:

```
myButton.setStyle("fx-background-color: #FFF");
```

The latter fails do change the color though. Could it be that once ive set my stylesheet that I cant override it? How can I change the button color on click?

Comment: Do you want to change the color on press and then fallback to the original color or do you want to change the color on first click and then to sustain the same color?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha first click and sustain. Could it be that im missing a dash before fx? XD omg. I wonder if this question is worth deleting lol

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to do a similar thing(here is simplified, there is just the part of code which change the style to the button) and i did this, i hope it will be helpful to you

```
button.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
    button.getStyleClass().removeAll("addBobOk, focus"); 
    //In this way you're sure you have no styles applied to your object button
    button.getStyleClass().add("addBobOk");
    //then you specify the class you would give to the button
});
```

CSS:

```
.addBobOk{
        -fx-background-color:#90EE90;
        -fx-background-radius: 5,5,4;
        -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0,0,1;
        -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.4) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );
        -fx-text-alignment: center;
}
.addBobOk:hover{

        -fx-background-color:#64EE64;
        -fx-effect: dropshadow( three-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.4) , 5, 0.0 , 0 , 1 );
        -fx-text-alignment: center;
}
.busy{

        -fx-background-color:#B3B3B3; 
        -fx-text-alignment: center;
}
.busy:hover{

        -fx-background-color:cdcbcb;                       
        -fx-text-alignment: center;
}
```

Comment: Thats pretty nice. Thanks. Would you recommend it over setStyle?

Comment: What is the second argument 'focus' in removeAll();

Comment: It's an other class defined in the css, sorry, maybe i forget it when i wrote the answer

Answer (score 1):

[Styling FX Buttons with CSS](http://fxexperience.com/2011/12/styling-fx-buttons-with-css/) show some applicable style options for a button.

"fx-background-color" is just a typo. It needs to be "-fx-background-color".

To use the styles you need to get the style names and values correct and separate them with semicola. The following approach does this systematically:

```
  String bstyle=String.format("-fx-text-fill: %s;-fx-fill: %s;-fx-background-color: %s;",textFill,fill, bgColor);
  button.setStyle(bstyle);
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have a solution. Check this out:**

```
.myButton:focused {
    -fx-background-color: #FFF
}
```

`:focus` will work in normal CSS. But in JavaFX CSS it's different.
So, use `:focused`