# javafx - button setStyle -fx-graphics doesn't change the icon of the button

Tags: java, css, javafx

I implemented **i18n** into my project. I have a button with `-fx-graphic: url("../icons/x16/en-US.png");` css style. When I click on the button the language changes, the icon doesn't.

I want to change the css-style for `-fx-graphics` on my button onclick.

This doesn't work and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. Since doing the same using `button.setText("sometext");` works just fine, I believe it has something to do with the stage/scene.

```
    public class Main extends Application {
        private static Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);
        private static Stage primaryStage;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
            this.primaryStage = stage;

            ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n.mytool", new Locale("en", "US"));
            loadMainView(bundle);
        }

        public void loadMainView(ResourceBundle bundle) throws IOException {
            LOG.debug("Create FXMLLoader");
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("fxml/Main.fxml"), bundle);

            LOG.debug("Create parent");
            Parent parentRoot = fxmlLoader.load();

            LOG.debug("Set Scene");
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(parentRoot));

            LOG.debug("Show Scene");
            primaryStage.show();
        }
    }
```

On my MainView.java I do:

```
    public void initialize() {
        btnLang.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                LOG.debug("btnLang setOnAction");
                btnLang.setStyle("-fx-graphic: url('/icons/x16/de-DE.png');");
// when commenting the reload the button changes it's icon ..                
try {
                    LOG.debug("btnLang setOnAction try");
                    main.loadMainView(ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n.mytool", new Locale("de", "DE")));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOG.debug("btnLang setOnAction catch");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I also tried using this method [39820837](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39820837/changing-javafx-button-color-on-click) but the same result.

I don't get any error or warning on both tries.

**Update:**
Two mistakes were made. First of all, I used a wrong path due to copy & pasting ... then I found out that my way of reloading is the problem. I don't know how to rsolve this, but when I simply use the onclick action without reloading the button chages it's icon.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the relationship between the two chunks of code, but doesn't `main.loadMainView(...)` completely replace the UI?

Comment: @James_D My intention was (due to the i18n implementation), to change the language without restarting the application, which results in a UI reload.