# JavaFX button pressed issue

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

I need that when I press a button, the button color changes, Im making the interface in scene builder and style it with fx css. I tried:

```
.botones:hover { 
    -fx-background-color: red;
}

.botones:pressed {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}

.botones { 
    -fx-background-color:  #262626;
}
```

The hover works fine, but when i press the button, it turns blue for a second and then changes to its original color and i want it to stay blue.

Maybe i could use a toggle button instead, but im using jfoenix buttons because they have some cool effects.

Comment: does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39820837/changing-javafx-button-color-on-click/39826183

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that the `ToggleButton` in [JFoenix](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix) is more of a switch:

[image: JFXToggleButton]

However, you can use a lesser-known control in JFoenix called [`JFXToggleNode`](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/85674ebf0554c6e76df6c410f47d3f7d001e45e1/jfoenix/src/main/java/com/jfoenix/controls/JFXToggleNode.java).

[image: JFXToggleNode Animation]

Just put a label inside of it. (Don't forget to include the `import` statements.)

```
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXToggleNode?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

...

<JFXToggleNode>
    <Label text="Boton Azul" />
</JFXToggleNode>
```

and add this rule to your stylesheet:

```
.jfx-toggle-node {
    /* This is the color once toggled on. */
    -jfx-toggle-color: deepskyblue;
}
```

Note that SceneBuilder doesn't support non-standard controls very well, yet, so though you *can't* drag and drop it, you *can* add it manually to the FXML file *just fine*.

Comment: Okay so i tried adding the button throught the fxml file, but what happens is that the button is always blue, i click on it and it is still blue, but thanks anyway!

Comment: I got you covered, @JAram. See the edits I've made. The `-jfx-toggle-color` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @JAram, I've added a picture of the final product.

Comment: Sorry i wasnt able to answer yesterday, however i tried it now, i added the toggle node throught FXML file and then i added the style in the css file, but for some reason its not working.

Comment: If you want to update your question with what you've got now, I might be able to help.

Comment: Hey i just solved it!, what i did was:. fx-toggle-node {
 -fx-background-color:  #262626;
        -fx-selected-color: blue
} And it works perfectly!

Comment: You can surround your code with backticks there in the comments if you'd like to format it. The backtick key is the one right under `Esc`

Comment: Now i need to make that a toggle node gets unselected when i select another node. But thats a different story ^^